# How do I insert code block header :var in exported code block in org-mode for SQL

Tags: org-mode, org-export, sql

I cannot repeat solution mentioned in [27610](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/27610) for SQL. Seems there is no `org-babel-variable-assignments:sql` function in `org.el`.